# Python - Changing File Object within function

Tags: python, file, function, object

Sorry - My questions is how can I change a file object within a function from a different function?

I've been trying to work out this error in my first python script for too long now, Dr Google and the forums aren't helping me too much, but I'm hoping you can.

I have a looping function that generates alot of data and I would like to output it to a text file, and create a new text file after the third loop.
I have 2 functions defined, one to create the data hashes, the other to create the new files.

The new files are being created as expected (aaa.txt, baa.txt...etc) but the "hashit" function only ever writes to the first file (aaa.txt) even though the others are being created.

I have tried fo.close() fo.flush(), as well as referencing fo in the functions but can't seem to make it work. Also I've moved the fo.write from the function to the main body.

I have included a cut down version of the code that I've been using to troubleshoot this issue, the real one has several more loops increasing the string length.

Thanks in advance

```
import smbpasswd, hashlib
base = '''abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '''
# base length 95
print(base)

baselen = len(base)
name = 'aaa.txt'
fo = open(name, "w")
print "Name of the file: ", fo.name
print "Closed or not : ", fo.closed
print "Opening mode : ", fo.mode
print "Softspace flag : ", fo.softspace
pw01 = 0
pw02 = 0
pw03 = 0

def hashit(passwd):
    #2
    # Need to install module
    # sudo apt-get install python-smbpasswd
    hex_dig_lm = smbpasswd.lmhash(passwd)               
    hex_dig_ntlm = smbpasswd.nthash(passwd)
    #print '%s:%s' % smbpasswd.hash(passwd)
    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5(passwd)
    hex_dig_md5 = hash_md5.hexdigest()

    print(passwd)
    print(hex_dig_lm)
    print(hex_dig_ntlm)
    print(hex_dig_md5)
    hashstring = passwd +","+ hex_dig_lm +","+ hex_dig_md5 + '\n'
    fo.write(hashstring);

def newfile(name):
    fo.flush()
    fo = open(name, "a")
    print("-------newfile------")
    print "Name of the file: ", fo.name
    print "Closed or not : ", fo.closed
    print('NewFile : ' + name)
    raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")

# add 3rd digit
while (pw03 < baselen):
    pwc03 = base[pw03]
    name = pwc03 + 'aa.txt'
    fo.close
    newfile(name);
    pw03 += 1 
    while (pw02 < baselen):
        pwc02 = base[pw02]
        pw02 += 1
        while (pw01 < baselen):
            pwc01 = base[pw01]
            pw01 += 1
            passwd = pwc03 + pwc02 + pwc01
            hashit(passwd);
        else:
            pw01 = 0   
    else:
           pw02 = 0
else:
    pw03 = 0
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You have too many `else` in your code; what is the actual problem?

Comment: Thanks for your input, I used the else to reset the counters to 0, the section under "#add 3rd digit" is replacated for 4th digit and 5 digit etc.  The problem is the fo.write(hashstring); statement under the hashit function only ever writes to aaa.txt even though I change the fo to baa.txt, caa.txt etc.   newfile correctly makes baa.txt but hashit still uses aaa.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your newfile() function, add this line first:

```
global fo
```

Comment: I marked as answered, but it won't let me +1 you as I am a new user but here's an unofficial +1 anyway... thanks again